# How to detect range of positions of specific set of characters in a string

Tags: r, regex, string, tidyverse, stringr

I have the following sequence:

```
my_seq <- "----?????-----?V?D????-------???IL??A?---"
```

What I want to do is to detect range of positions of non-dashed characters.

```
----?????-----?V?D????-------???IL??A?---
|   |   |     |      |       |       |  
1   5   9    15     22      30      38
```

The final output will be a vector of strings:

```
out <- c("5-9", "15-22", "30-38")
```

How can I achieve that with R?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Please find below, one other possible solution using the `stringr` library

**Reprex**

- Code

```r
library(stringr)

s <- as.data.frame(str_locate_all(my_seq, "[^-]+")[[1]])
result <- paste(s$start, s$end, sep ="-")
```

- Output

```r
result
#> [1] "5-9"   "15-22" "30-38"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 6):

You could do:

```r
my_seq <- "----?????-----?V?D????-------???IL??A?---"

non_dash <- which(strsplit(my_seq, "")[[1]] != '-')
pos      <- non_dash[c(0, diff(non_dash)) != 1 | c(diff(non_dash), 0) != 1]

apply(matrix(pos, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE), 1, function(x) paste(x, collapse = "-"))
#> [1] "5-9"   "15-22" "30-38"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 5):

Inspired from @lovalery's great answer, a `base R` solution is:

```r
g <- gregexpr(pattern = "[^-]+", my_seq)
d <-data.frame(start = unlist(g), 
           end = unlist(g) + attr(g[[1]], "match.length") - 1)
paste(s$start, s$end, sep ="-")
# [1] "1-5"   "11-18" "26-34"
```

Answer (score 5):

A one-liner in base R with `utf8ToInt`

```
apply(matrix(which(diff(c(FALSE, utf8ToInt(my_seq) != 45L, FALSE)) != 0) - 0:1, 2), 2, paste, collapse = "-")
#> [1] "5-9"   "15-22" "30-38"
```

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
paste0(gregexec('-\\?', my_seq)[[1]][1,] + 1, '-',
       gregexec('\\?-', my_seq)[[1]][1,])
#> [1] "5-9"   "15-22" "30-38"
```

Comment: This does not give the good result for `my_seq <- "?????-----?V?D????-------???IL??A?---"`.

Comment: @Maël, why not? Here it worked fine. It's hard to think of a good regex.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a rle + tidyverse approach:

```r
library(dplyr)
with(rle(strsplit(my_seq, "")[[1]] != "-"),
     data.frame(lengths, values)) |>
  mutate(end = cumsum(lengths)) |>
  mutate(start =  1 + lag(end, 1,0)) |>
  mutate(rng = paste(start, end, sep = "-")) |>
  filter(values) |>
  pull(rng)

[1] "5-9"   "15-22" "30-38"
```

However if you don't mind installing `S4Vectors` the code can be made really terse:

```r
library(S4Vectors)

r <- Rle(strsplit(my_seq, "")[[1]] != "-")

paste(start(r), end(r), sep = "-")[runValue(r)]

[1] "5-9"   "15-22" "30-38"
```